# Prevent nautilus showing partition mounted in bash script

Tags: nautilus, bash

In my bash script I mount partitions, check them, copy files to them, and unmount. When the script mounts the partition, Nautilus pops up with a Window showing the partition and stealing focus. This is something I want to avoid.

Note: I know I can change the behaviour of this in System settings, Details, Removable media, `Never prompt or start programs on media insertion`, but I don't want to change the behaviour e.g. if a USB stick is plugged in, I just want to prevent it in my bash script. Since this script runs on other users' computers I cannot modify these settings (in the script) because if it is terminated abnormally it will leave the modified settings in place (I also don't believe it should be necessary to do this).

Actually this auto display doesn't seem consistent. If I do the exact same command from the terminal, Nautilus doesn't show, and I know there are other mounts in my script that don't show. So what could be causing this? Here's an example of the code (both cause separate nautilus windows to pop):

```
mount $dev $target
mkdir -p $target/home
mount $homedev $target/home
```

I'm interested in understanding the process by which the mount signals Nautilus and why this is happening (when it doesn't if I mount the partition from the terminal). And what is the best way to prevent this from happening.

I noticed this behaviour starting on release 11.10 (if I recall correctly). I'm currently running 12.04, but the script has to work on all supported releases. I don't believe the solution should involve modifying system settings (that might differ between releases). For example, if you look at other things that mount partitions (like os-prober), there are no nautilus windows popping up when it mounts different partitions.

The script can be found [here](https://github.com/bcbc/Wubi-move). And [here's the part](https://github.com/bcbc/Wubi-move/blob/master/wubi-move.sh#L560) where Nautilus pops. I think it also pops [here](https://github.com/bcbc/Wubi-move/blob/master/wubi-move.sh#L798), but I've been focusing my testing on the first link. [This](https://github.com/bcbc/Wubi-move/blob/master/check-target.sh#L213) is where it doesn't pop, called prior to those other mounts - note I've rewritten the first ones as --read-only and within an if statement and it makes no difference.

Ideally the answer will explain why this is happening and how to prevent it, in other words, explain why the in-script `mount` is treated differently to the one issued from a terminal. A good workaround will also be accepted if it is a fully explained solution and practical that can support all desktop environments (ubuntu, kubuntu, xubuntu, lubuntu etc) - I also want to avoid an exponential increase in testing to verify it.

Thanks in advance

============

Solution as per *papashou*'s link:

```
add_udev_rules ()
{
    for i in "$dev" "$homedev" "$bootdev" "$usrdev"; do
      if [ -n "$i" ]; then
        block=${i#/dev/}
        echo "KERNEL==\"""$block""\",ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}=\"1\"" >> "$wubi_move_dir"/wubi_move.rules
      fi
    done
    cp "$wubi_move_dir"/wubi_move.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/wubi_move.rules
    udevadm trigger > /dev/null 2>&1
}

remove_udev_rules ()
{
    rm /etc/udev/rules.d/wubi_move.rules
    rm "$wubi_move_dir"/wubi_move.rules
    udevadm trigger > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

This achieves the desired result, but feels like a sledgehammer approach. I believe there is probably a fine-tuning in udev that will allow the partition to still show in Nautilus (and other file browsers) without popping up when it's mounted. By the way if anyone wants to try this, the following script will show the pop-up effect of nautilus:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/testmount
mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/testmount
sleep 3
umount /dev/sda1 
mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/testmount
sleep 3
umount /dev/sda1 
mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/testmount
sleep 3
umount /dev/sda1 
mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/testmount
sleep 3
umount /dev/sda1 
rmdir /tmp/testmount
```

I'm going to keep playing with `udev` and I've also filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/986269), since this doesn't make any sense for a partition that's not inserted to act like an inserted USB/media card upon mount. Also the `udevadm trigger` is not an inexpensive operation that appears (on 12.04 at least) to temporarily freeze everything.

So, in summary, I have a workable solution (thanks to everyone who helped out), which I may or may not implement (not sure yet); but I'll keep looking for something else.
Thanks

Comment: For others answering, could you add your Ubuntu Version? e.g. 9.04, 10.10, 12.04. There was a fair bit of evolution from one to another.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit my question to add that.

Comment: if you mount -i does it keep nautilus from popping up? It works for me for keeping gnome-shell from popping up with the little dialog at the bottom of the screen. This was tested on 12.04 Ubuntu using gnome-shell.

Comment: That makes no difference for me.

Comment: <p>_If I do the exact same command from the terminal, Nautilus doesn't show_ - How do you launch your script? </p>

<p> _and I know there are other mounts in my script that don't show_ - What differences between these mounts?</p>

Comment: I launch it with `sudo bash ...` Re. the difference between the mounts, if I knew the answer to that I wouldn't have posted the question ;) I'll update the question with a link to the script, but it's pretty long.

Comment: Update: during some experimentation with udevd and udevadm (which didn't show much promise; just looking at --debug output) - I noticed that nautilus DOES pop with a normal `mount` from terminal. So, this problem isn't limited just to scripts. No closer to a solution, but this actually makes more sense!? (that the behaviour is consistent, not specifically related to the script). Although I guess still inconsistent as it doesn't always happen.(!?)

Comment: Shameless plug: it sounds like this software I made could be useful to you: https://github.com/ali1234/autoflash/ It uses udisks instead of mount shell command so you have a bit more control over what happens.

Comment: IMHO adding a udev rule then removing it is just as bad as temporarily changing system settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this suggestion: http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/969/hide-your-disks-or-partitions-from-nautilus/

I'm fairly sure it has to do with udev signals and processing.

Comment: Can you post the link's content concisely here? An answer with just a link is not very welcome in AU community.

Comment: This works. At the moment there's too little detail to accept the answer. I have confirmed manually that it works to create the file and call `udevadm trigger`. Just want to confirm it works in the script. I'll post the details in the question if you haven't added more here.

Comment: I didn't want to re-summarize what the link has already laid out clearly.  Basically, it requires adding a rule in  /etc/udev/rules.d/ that tells udev to not process specific devices  -- each device would get their own line specifying: KERNEL==”sda1″, ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}=”1″.  Doing so doesn't modify any system or kernel behavior.  It just tells UDEV to hide the presentation of the disk.   Nautilus relies on udev rule processing for precisely this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

# disable nautilus automount
#
gconftool --type Boolean --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount  false

# put your script here  
#
...

# enable back nautilus automount
# 
gconftool --type Boolean --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount  true
```

Not tested cause I'm on 10.04

**UPDATE:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#

# disable nautilus automount
#
gconftool --type Boolean --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount  false

# put CALLING your script here to survive its crashes
#
/bin/bash -c "/whenever/it/is/placed/script.sh"

# enable back nautilus automount
# 
gconftool --type Boolean --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount  true
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I don't want to modify the settings because I'm not sure it will take effect immediately, it requires different code for each release, it is inelegant, and if the script is aborted it leaves the user in an undesired state - I also don't believe it should be necessary. What I am after is the mechanism by which nautilus is notified of the mount, and how to bypass it. e.g. udev? dbus? that sort of thing.

Comment: + *I don't want to modify the settings because I'm not sure it will take effect immediately* - That is the question to be checked out (easy enough).
+ *it requires different code for each release* - it **may** require or **may not** 50|50 as if I could meet a dyno at the street ))
+ *it is inelegant* - comparing to what alternative?

Comment: + *if the script is aborted it leaves the user in an undesired state* - many packages (aptitude e.g) when aborted do so. There are approaches to avoid that side effect. E.g. you can charge cron to check every 1min if script is running, and if not to change the setting back. Or you can run you script from another which controls the setting.

Comment: My point is that it shouldn't be required to change a desktop specific setting. I should also have added that this script can run on ubuntu/xubuntu/kubuntu/lubuntu etc. so it adds a high level of complexity and risk.

Comment: The alternative of blacklisting the partition with udisk(see papashous link) require sudo and is not portable across machines, so it would be even more complex and risky.

Comment: The script can only run with `sudo` (mounting would not be possible otherwise otherwise). It should work across all Ubuntu based machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent flash drive automounting by adding a new udev rule. In that rule you can specify a flash drive by its vendor, serial number, other attributes. See *ATTRS{}* lines in the output of:

```
udevadm info -a --name=sdb1
```

That script you should place into */etc/udev/rules.d* folder with special file name, e.g.
*81-usb-wubi-move.rules*

The rule could look like

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sdb?", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="001CC07CEE5EFB91C91B235C", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY}="1"
```

See also:

- [How to understand the flow of USB detection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18374/how-to-understand-the-flow-of-usb-detection)
- [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)
- [udev rule to hide partitions from thunar [solved]](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-893102-start-0.html)
- [HakAday - How to write udev rules](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/)

Comment: This seems like it should be potential workaround - I need time to review this and experiment, and won't have a chance until later today (will give feedback then). Ideally the answer will explain why this is happening (as compared to running `mount` from the terminal) but if I get a good workaround I'll accept that too.

Comment: This is the one

Answer (score 0):

Untested.... just a hunch.

Mount the filesystem in a tree inaccessible to the nautilus user, e.g. in a subdirectory of /root or /home/someoneelse or a /tmp subdirectory owned and secured by someone else

Keep in mind it might be a bad idea to mount the same hardware device at two mountpoints and modify it from both.

Some human configuration is possible in (12.04beta) Ubuntu->System Settings->Details->Removable Media . Some of the options could be set to "do nothing" and that might avoid the popup.

The documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB might be helpful for 9.10 but did not work with 12.04.  The keys for gconf-editor that they mention are no longer used.

Comment: It is mounted in a directory under /tmp (and nowhere else).

Comment: But the logged in user can still access /tmp.  The suggestion was to use a directory that the logged-in user can not access.

Comment: I used `chmod 700` on the dir... looked promising and then up popped an message window (with no window title): "Unable to open a folder for 10 GB Filesystem", "No application is registered as handling this file"

Comment: Fascinating.  It sure tries hard. Maybe I'll have time to play with this later.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mount` with the `-n` and `-i` flags.

Comment: I've tried that - pretty much been through all the mount options that I can. The trigger is happening elsewhere.